# How to call CORBA interface from C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, corba

How to call CORBA interface from C#?

Comment: Of course you can if your ORB has a C# binding available.  If not, you're out of luck.  Which one are you using?

Comment: Isn't CORBA (just like .NET Remoting) heavily outdated? Time to use a web service.

Comment: Yes CORBA is out but have some legacy code which should be infarct with C# code. Anyway we are using OMNI ORB 4.x.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can call CORBA interface using c#.
here the link that will help you [Calling CORBA Interface using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031381/how-to-access-corba-interface-without-idl-or-late-bound-invoke-remoting-methods)